# when I open text file that in russian I see Hebrew letters (gibrish)

Tags: language

When I open a russian text file I see it in gibrish (Hebrew letters), in spite of that I can write in russian.

How can I see that file in russian (not gibrish)?
I use WIN7
(This file is a movie subtitle file)

Answer (score 0):

Open it in a text editor that supports multiple encodings (such as Geany) and try various encodings until you find the correct one.

Comment: Tried it, didn't find the correct one...

Comment: And use font, which supports all these codepages

Comment: I used arial that should support all.